# ASP.NET Identity for WebForms - getting started with extending User attributes

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm working on my first ASP.NET WebForms project using Identity.  I ticked the box when creating the project and the basics all seem to be working OK.  Now I want to extend the Register form and the AspNetUsers table with new attributes (e.g. Users (actual) Name).  I'd also like to expose the existing PhoneNumber attribute.

I did some research but couldn't find any non-MVC info on this scenario.  Is the expectation that I just hack away at the template code to achieve this?

I'm happy to do so, just wondering if I am missing something...

Comment: Why not look at the generated markup and make modifications as you see fit? As for adding properties, you can add them to your `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from `IdentityUser`. Then update your database (or use migrations to perform the update).

Comment: That's pretty much what I was planning (summarized as "hack away").  It just doesnt seem to be explicitly stated anywhere. Thanks for the speedy reply.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are using an ASP.NET Web From with default files and folders.
Please open the IdentityMode.cs in Models folder and find ApplicationUser class.
In this class you can add user attributes as properties, see example :
**01: add profile information in users table:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserFullName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }


    }
```

**02 :
you can add profile information in different table :**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    }

public class UserInfo
{

        [Required]
        public string UserFullName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
}
```